# Flurry on iOS and full stacktrace

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, crash-reports, flurry

Is there a way on Flurry to get the full stacktrace of crash reports?

Currently, I only see this (sample) in the Exception Log page:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value 
(key: someKey)
Msg: Crash!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not sure but as far as i know with Flurry each crash is limited to 255 chars, and we can't see the complete stack trace.

I could suggest other bug tracking services -

1. [crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/)
2. [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/) is another bug tracking service for iOS, Android and WP7.
3. [AirBrake](https://airbrakeapp.com/) seems to be really nice and has plans from free (i.e. just one project, user) to extra large (i.e. 64 projects, users).
4. [TestFlight SDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc)
5. [HopToad](http://airbrakeapp.com/pages/home)

Also Apple itself provides you with crash reports. Go to iTunesConnect, Manage Your Applications, View Details and then select the crash reports link.

[image]

You'll get crash reports broken down by operating system version which is really useful.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I have tried iTunesConnect before, but it keeps showing me that there are too few reports. I'll check the other alternatives!

Comment: so which one did u end up using ?

Comment: I will be using TestFlight as the others seem to come with some limitations for the free version, and we already use TestFlight for beta testing so it makes sense. Have you tried any of those?

Comment: yupp testflight it is :) plus they are coming out with something called Testflight Live - seems impressive https://testflightapp.com/sdk/live/

Comment: Just in case anyone comes here: iTunes Connect only shows crash reports when users agree to sending them AND they connect their device to a computer - so chances are you won't see a single crash report for your app nowadays in iTunes Connect ...

Comment: I would also suggest Crashlytics (have been using it for a while and love it).